# Preserving Drop Down Menu when Mouse Hovered and leaves

Tags: c#, user-interface

Like we see on various Websites, where a Dropdown list comes as soon as You hover mouse on the menu title. As shown in Screen shot (Mouse is just hovered over "Log").

[image: Drop Down Menu]

For this, I wrote code as

```
private void logToolStripMenuItem_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        logToolStripMenuItem.ShowDropDown();
    }
```

Objective was achieved but problem was Menu remained as it is unless I click somewhere else.
So I Added,

```
private void logToolStripMenuItem_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        logToolStripMenuItem.HideDropDown();
    }
```

But Problem was whenever I move mouse to "Configure" to select the Menu item, Drop Down Menu disappears (As Mouse "Leaves" Menu item). What should I do, So that:-
1. Drop down list is shown when I hovered mouse on Log.
2. I should be able to Select Menu Options
3. Drop down list should hide when Mouse leaves the area.

I am using VS2010 and Coding in C#

Thanks!